# How to map a Reader with a function dependant of this environment

Tags: scala, scalaz

Given a `Reader[E, A]` and a function `(E, A) => B`, how can I get a `Reader[E, B]` ? Is there an existing function in scalaz.

For the moment, I wrote this little function :

```
def map2[E, A, B](reader: Reader[E, A], f: (E, A) => B) : Reader[E, B] = {
  Reader { e => f(e, reader(e)) }
}
```

Comment: Off the top of my head I can't think of a single combinator that would do this. I guess you could argue that `reader <*> Reader(e => f(e, _))` makes the readerliness a little more apparent, but I find your version clearer.